# No module named grp on windows Python 2.7.11

Tags: python-2.7

Python 2.7.11 is installed on a Windows 10 machine. A Python tool called Pulsar (https://pulsar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) which is designed to be cross OS was installed successfully. However when I tried to start the tool, some error message "ImportError: No module named grp" turned up. It seems that grp module is for linux group function which naturally should not be available on windows, but as said before Pulsar is supposed to be able to run on any OS. How to solve this problem? Many thanks!

Comment: have you checked if you are on the correct environment?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67686736/12201407 most recent answer