# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'grp' on windows

Tags: python, django, windows, redis, celery

As i was going through the Celery implementation from the Celery documentation,

```
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=INFO
```

gave output unexpected that from the documentation,

> File
> "d:\101_all_projects\celery-testing\venv\lib\site-packages\celery\platforms.py",
> line 9, in 
> import grp ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'grp'

Is this because i am on windows?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you're using the PyPi package **django-celery-beat** it looks like it installs the most recent version of the required package **celery** rather than installing a compatible version (by the time I'm posting this, 25th of May 2021 this would be **v5.1.0**), which seems to have compatibility issues with **django-celery-beat** version **2.2.0** (the most recent) as well as Windows OS.

I suggest you try

```
pip uninstall celery
pip install celery==5.0.5
```

Answer (score 2):

This is fixed with celery `^5.1.1` as you can see [here](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/changelog.html#id2). You just need to update celery now

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i agree with you. For me also it happens, exact same issue

when i was working on installations in a command prompt, i was mentioned as (pip install celery), it was installed recent version (5.1.0) or (pip install -r requirements.txt) mentioned in requirements.txt version

```
pip uninstall celery
pip install celery==5.0.5
```

It is working

Also, whenever you are working celery make sure youare changes in your requirements.txt as required version as mentione below after run this command (pip install -r requirements.txt)

> #We need to mentioned as celery==5.0.5 in our requirement.tx

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
#it will also working make sure you mentioned the exact version in your reqiuirements.txt
```